# Pass a parameter from client-side to server side and get result

Tags: json, ajax, api

I knows it sounds basic but I can't seem to get it right. I'm trying to get a data from the API but it needs a parameter in order to obtain the data. How can I pass the parameter and get the result which is a JSON array

```
$(function() {


    var proxy       = 'http://192.168.1.126/lms-dev-noel/proxy.php';
    var endpoint    = 'account/';
    var rt          = 'GET';
    var url         = proxy+'?endpoint='+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;
    var param       = {
        'lastsyncdate' : '2016-12-06'
    };

    $.get(url, function(param) {
        console.log('Success');
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ways to achieve this :**

1. using [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method **:**

   ```
   var proxy = 'http://192.168.1.126/lms-dev-noel/proxy.php';
   var endpoint    = 'account/';
   var url = proxy+'?endpoint='+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;
   var method = 'GET';
   var params = {
      'lastsyncdate' : '2016-12-06'
   };

   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: method, //send it through get method
       data: params,
       success: function(response) {
           //Do Something
       },
       error: function(xhr) {
           //Do Something to handle error
       }
   });
   ```
2. using [**jQuery.get()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method **:**

   ```
   var proxy = 'http://192.168.1.126/lms-dev-noel/proxy.php';
   var endpoint    = 'account/';
   var url = proxy+'?endpoint='+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;
   var method = 'GET';
   var params = {
       'lastsyncdate' : '2016-12-06'
   };

   $.get(url, params, function(res) {
       console.log(res);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I just pass parameters as name value pairs like so...

```
$.get(
    "yoururl.php", 
    { color: "red", size: "small" }, // your params go here as name / value pairs
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm isn't this the same as the one you posted `$.get(url, function(param) { console.log('Success');  });`